# RNNs' Training in different batch_size result in different performance?

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

After reading RNN source code in Pytorch and some blogs regarding with RNN, I want to verify my thoughts about RNN training. That is, for example, **if we set batch_size from 1 to 4, the training process is totally different.**

Here is the explanation about *nn.RNNN()* in Pytorch documentation.

> `h_n` of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)

if `batch_size = 1`, then we only get one init hidden state (typically is a tensor with all zeros). While if `batch_size = 4`, we get four init hidden states, which means the input hidden state of RNN training in the fourth word now is different from the input hidden state of previous training process.

Considering the former one, the input hidden state of fourth word in this process (`batch_size=1`) contains the information of first three words, while the other one is totally zero.

So, can anybody tells me whether my thoughts are right or not?

Comment: Incorrect.

The batch size captures no temporal information but rather the amount of distinct sequences to be processed in parallel.
This is however not a coding related question, and as such it does not belong in SO.

Comment: From a higher perspective and not consider the detailed implementation about RNN in pytorch, I totally agree with your answer @KonstantinosKokos. However, just considering the detail implementation as I listed in my question part, we do input 4 initialized hidden states into `nn.RNN` part as `batch_size = 4`. 


While in the training with `batch_size = 1`, we only input one initialized tensor in the RNN. Therefore, I think there are some slight differences between different batch_size?

Comment: No. Each hidden vector `h[b]` for b in `batch_size` serves as the initial hidden vector for the corresponding input sequence `x[b]`. There is no computation between `h[i]` and `x[j][t]` for any `t` and `i != j`.